# IComparer not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

My program's function is to count the occurrences of unique words in a document, and then display them in sorted order. I first loop through all the words and enter them into a dictionary, and increment the value in the dictionary for how many times they have been encountered. I then convert the dictionary to a list and call the `.Sort` method with an `IComparer` as a parameter. Shown in this code here:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,long>> wordList = wordCount.ToList();
IComparer<KeyValuePair<string,long>> comparison = new comparator();
wordList.Sort(comparison);
```

And the IComparer class I am using

```
public class comparator : IComparer<KeyValuePair<string, long>>
{
    public int Compare(KeyValuePair<string, long> x, KeyValuePair<string, long> y)
    {
        if (x.Value > y.Value)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

However, when I am finished with the sorting, the list is not ordered by the value of the KeyValuePair like as I hoped it would be. What am I doing wrong here?

[image: screen shot of poor sorting order]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the case when `y.Value` is greater than `x.Value` in your comparer implementation:

```
public class comparator : IComparer<KeyValuePair<string, long>>
{
    public int Compare(KeyValuePair<string, long> x, KeyValuePair<string, long> y)
    {
        if (x.Value > y.Value)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (x.Value < y.Value)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

or

```
public class comparator : IComparer<KeyValuePair<string, long>>
{
    public int Compare(KeyValuePair<string, long> x, KeyValuePair<string, long> y)
    {
        return x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value);
    }
}
```

You could also use LINQ `OrderBy` instead of `Sort`. It's easier to use because it takes a lambda expression, but it will create a new collection, instead of sorting the provided one.

```
var sorted = wordList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

You could do all your processing in one query (assuming `words` is a collection of strings with all the words):

```
var sortedWithCount = words.GroupBy(x => x)
                           .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
                           .ToList(g => new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count });
```

Comment: oh man. That was it. Somehow in my mind i thought i only needed the single case. Thanks for the answer. Ill accept it at 10min.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should return `1`, `0` and `-1` as a result fo the Compare method. But in your case, you could just use the `CompareTo` method from `long` type, for sample:

```
public class Comparator : IComparer<KeyValuePair<string, long>>
{
    public int Compare(KeyValuePair<string, long> x, KeyValuePair<string, long> y)
    {
        return x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value);
    }
}
```

As a good pratice, rename your class to `Comparator` and not `comparator`. Keep the clean code on!